# How can I implement enum in a graph database like Neo4j?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, neo4j, nosql

I want to implement an `enum` for `Neo4j`.It is very easy on `ActiveRecord` like

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [ :active, :archived ]
end
```

How can I implement this in Neo4j?

Comment: I am disappointed not sure why I got the down vote for this.I am really facing this issue can someone help me with this.Should not someone add comment if I were unable to explain the question properly?

Answer (score 2):

Enums are now supported by the Neo4j driver, so you can do this:

```
class Media
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode

  enum type: [:image, :video, :unknown]
end

media = Media.create(type: :video)
media.type
# => :video
media.image!
media.image?
# => true
```

See the documentation for more details: http://neo4jrb.readthedocs.io/en/8.1.x/ActiveNode.html?highlight=default#enums

Answer (score 1):

The `neo4j` gem doesn't yet support this, but I think it could be a good idea.  If you want it in the meantime you might implement a `Concern` that you could `include` into your model.

I've also created an issue to suggest implementing this: https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/issues/1082

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Brian Underwood suggestion.I have implemented the solution by creating a module in `lib/enum_attr.rb`.

I have a model `user.rb` in which I have to implement enum so I have created `enum_attr` method in that like

```
  class User
    enum_attr status: [ :active, :archived ]
  end
```

Add a module `lib/enum_attr.rb`

```
  module ClassMethods
    def enum_attr(attr_list)
      attr_list.each do |list|
        enum_name, enum_data = list.first, list.second

        enum_data.each_with_index do |method_name,value|
          define_method("#{method_name}?") do
            enum_value = self.send(enum_name)
            enum_value.nil? ? false : enum_data[enum_value] == method_name
          end

          define_method("#{method_name}!") do
            self.write_attribute(enum_name, value)
            self.save
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

**Explanation:**

I have added two methods.First one sets the value

```
user = User.first
user.active! # sets the user to active with value 0
```

and second returns a boolean method which checks in which status it is

```
user.active? # returns true/false as per the result
user.archived? #returns false if it it set to active
```